# Where is Enumeration<T> implemented?

Tags: java

I'm a C# Unity3D developer and I've recently had to jump into Java to create a plugin for an android game I am working on. Briefly, this plugin's purpose is to use java networking functions so a player can broadcast a match they're hosting on their phone for others to find on a LAN.

For this plugin I needed to get all the network interfaces on the device, filter out any local-link or loopback IPs and then (assuming there is only 1 remaining address, which there should be) use the remaining address for broadcasting. I've successfully done this, but I couldn't help be bothered by this line of my code:

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
```

I've become more curious about the inner workings of things lately. Unity3D has a great API and documentation but recently I've been using the included IDE (MonoDevelop) to view their managed source code to help me understand better how things are done, so this question is really just once again helping out my curiosity.

So, Enumeration is an interface which is implicitly abstract, and its functions are too, meaning a Class must implement it to define the behaviour of its functions.

Looking at NetworkInterface on docs.oracle.com, it does not appear to implement Enumeration, yet it has a function (shown above) which returns to me an Enumeration of type NetworkInterface with a functioning nextElement() function. Not only that, but because Enumeration is an interface, how can a function even provide me with one? Interfaces, like abstract classes, cannot be instantiated and yet I've been given this Enumeration instance with defined functions that I can call and it's holding the network interfaces I've asked for.

If it returned to me an object of some (obviously non-abstract) type which implemented Enumeration, perhaps holding a private array of type NetworkInterface, I think all of this would make more sense to me.

Comment: Interfaces are like a contract. The method you mention returns an object that obeys the contract defined by `java.util.Enumeration`, but doesn't promise anything beyond that. This is useful so that the implementation can be changed without any of the clients having to care (or even know) about it.

Comment: Suggestion for next time: There's a **lot** of irrelevant exposition above. I recommend just asking your question, clearly and succinctly. In this case, it could be about three sentences long.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Noted.

Sorry, just wanted to provide some background info so people kind of had an idea of my knowledge level and that the issue wasn't that the code wasn't working, it was just a question of how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Looking at NetworkInterface on docs.oracle.com, it does not appear to implement Enumeration...

Correct, it wouldn't make much sense for `NetworkInterface` *itself* to implement `Enumeration`, as it's not an enumeration. Instead, it has an *inner class* that it uses to implement the `Enumeration<NetworkInterface>`, and it's an instance of *that* class that you receive from `getNetworkInterfaces`.

This is a common pattern. You can see the implementation in the `NetworkInterface.java` file in the `src.zip` in your JDK install:

```
public static Enumeration<NetworkInterface> getNetworkInterfaces()
    throws SocketException {
    final NetworkInterface[] netifs = getAll();

    // specified to return null if no network interfaces
    if (netifs == null)
        return null;

    return new Enumeration<NetworkInterface>() {              // This is the
        private int i = 0;                                    // anonymous
        public NetworkInterface nextElement() {               // inner class used
            if (netifs != null && i < netifs.length) {        // to implement
                NetworkInterface netif = netifs[i++];         // Enumeration<NetworkInterface>
                return netif;                                 //
            } else {                                          //
                throw new NoSuchElementException();           //
            }                                                 //
        }                                                     //
                                                              //
        public boolean hasMoreElements() {                    //
            return (netifs != null && i < netifs.length);     //
        }                                                     //
    };                                                        //
}
```

In this case, it's an anonymous inner class. Other times they're named inner classes, such as `Itr` in `AbstractList.java` (also in `src.zip`).

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to do some research into inner & anonymous classes I think as that is a subject I'm not familiar with. 

The syntax confuses me a bit because it almost seems like it's returning a new instance of the Enumeration interface rather than a new object of a type implementing it (But that must be the trick of an anonymous class?). 

I suppose https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html will be a good place to start.

Comment: @hey-m8: Yes, that's exactly where to start. And yes, the syntax is indeed creating a new instance. It's doing two things at once: Creating an anonymous class that implements `Enumeration<NetworkInterface>` **and** then immediately creating an instance of that class and returning it.